# (Number of perfect powers ≤ n) ∼ $\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

The set $E$ of [perfect powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) is defined as follows: $$E:=\{x^y:\ x,y\in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ge 2} \}.$$ (Thus, a positive integer $n\in E$ iff the exponents in the prime factorization of $n$ have GCD $>1$.)

I was curious what the counting function for $E$ would look like, i.e., 
$$\epsilon(n) := \mathrm{card}\{k\in E:\ k\le n \},$$
so I computed $\epsilon(n)$ for $0\le n\le 10^6$, obtaining the following plot:

[image: counting function for exponential integers]
This picture is a superposition of $\epsilon(n)$ (black) and a fitted function of form $\ a\,n^b\ $ (red), with $a\approx 1.4,\ b\approx 0.48.$  Empirically, as $n$ increases, such fitted functions suggest that $\ \epsilon(n)\sim \sqrt{n}$.

**Question**: Is it correct that $\ \epsilon(n)\sim \sqrt{n}\ ?\ $ How can the correct asymptotic form be derived?

EDIT: Upon learning that these are called "perfect powers", I located several online articles proving $\ \epsilon(n)\sim \sqrt{n},\ $ including the following:

1. M. A. Nyblom, [A counting function for the sequence of perfect powers](https://researchbank.rmit.edu.au/eserv/rmit:397/n2006000023.pdf), Austral. Math. Soc. Gaz. 33 (2006), 338–343.
2. R. Jakimczuk, [On the distribution of perfect powers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL14/Jakimczuk3/jakimczuk21.pdf), J. Integer Seq. 14 (2011), Article 11.8.5.

Comment: Your formulation seems to avoid double-counting $2^4$ and $4^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: @VF1 - Yes, that's correct. It's the values, not the forms, that are counted.

Comment: This isn't relevant to your question, but here's an interesting fact about the set $E$: $\sum_{x \in E} \frac{1}{x} = 1.$

Comment: @JRichey - Very cool! Where might I read about that? Or is it easy to see?

Comment: @r.e.s. it's straightforward to check.

Comment: @JRichey - Apparently, it [turns out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power#Examples_and_sums) that $\sum_{x \in E} \frac{1}{x}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\mu(k)(1-\zeta(k)) \approx 0.874464368 \dots\ $ (As I pointed out above, set $E$ avoids duplicates such as $2^4$ and $4^2$; otherwise, apparently the sum would be $1$.)

Comment: Oh right, whoops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is that nearly all the members of $E$ are squares, and the number of squares $\le n$ is approximately $ \sqrt{n}$.

EDIT: More precisely: Every member of $E$ that is not a square is a $p$'th power for some  $p \ge 3$. The number of $p$'th powers $k^p$ with $1 < k^p\le n$ is $\lfloor n^{1/p} - 1 \rfloor$; this is $0$ if $2^p > n$, i.e. 
$p > \log_2(n)$.  So the number of members of $E$ that are not squares and $\le n$ is bounded by
$$ \sum_{3 \le p \le \log_2(n)} (n^{1/p}-1) \le \log_2(n) n^{1/3} = o(n^{1/2})$$

Comment: Well, it seems like $E$ contains all squares, cubes, fourth-powers, etc., So the answer is $\sum_i \lfloor n^{1/i}\rfloor - \text{double counted stuff}$. Why is that necessarily $O(\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: We may reasonably expect that $\epsilon(n)$ can be approximated by $\sum_{i}^{\log_2 n}n^{1/i}$ which is $O(\log(n)\sqrt n)$. Is there a way to reduce this to $O(\sqrt n)$, maybe using reasoning with collisions? Or am I missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.